# I want to blacklist mail in amavisd-new from a domain where sender addresses are utf8 encoded

Tags: email, amavis

In amavisd.conf I have

```
read_hash(\%blacklist_sender,'/etc/amavis/blacklist');
@blacklist_sender_maps = (\%blacklist_sender);`
```

In the blacklist file I have
`@example.com` (not the real domain)

However the sender address is always utf8 encoded so does not match the blacklist.  How can I blacklist this domain?